# Determining decomposition into orbits

Tags: symmetric-groups

Decompose the set $\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{C})$ of $2 \times 2$ complex matrices into orbits for the following operations of $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$: left multiplication.

Could someone give me a complete answer to this question? I have another "similar" question relation to conjugation. 
In addition to that I am practicing for an exam, and have other related problems and am kind of having difficulty understanding them. Would someone therefore have a link for similar type of problems (decomposition into orbits, determining stabilisers)

Comment: are you trying for classes of similar matrices??

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I don't understand your question. Could you rephrase it ?

Comment: You said, you want to see for orbits corresponding to conjugacy action.... $A$ is related to $B$ by conjugation iff $A$ and $B$ are similar.. Do you see why?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Ok but I first asked regarding the left multiplication, not conjugation.

Comment: I realized proof of similar matrices.. I am trying to see for left multiplication....

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I have a general question though. How would you generally proceed in order to determine the decomposition into orbits ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11175/discussion-between-user43418-and-praphulla-koushik)

Comment: @user43418 Did you ever figure this out?